# java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Erro de ES: Conexão fechada pela outra ponta, Authentication lapse 0 ms

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

tenho uma aplicação Java simples que faz uma conexão JDBC em um banco Oracle, segue o fonte.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + args[0] + ":1521/" + args[1], args[2],
                args[3]);
            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            }
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Disconnected to the database!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s \n", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Ao rodar a aplicação na minha máquina, informar os parâmetros via argumentos, ele conecta no banco normalmente, esse banco fica numa nuvem da Oracle que temos aqui na empresa.

Agora, exportei essa aplicação para um JAR e estou tentando executa-la em um servidor, nesse servidor, ao chamar o JAR passando os mesmo argumentos, no momento em que é executado o DriverManager.getConnection(); um erro é exibido após alguns segundos, segue o log de erro a baixo.

```
SQL State: 08006
Erro de ES: Conexão fechada pela outra ponta, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Erro de ES: Conexão fechada pela outra ponta, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:794)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at br.com.teste.oracle.Main.main(Main.java:11)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Conexão fechada pela outra ponta, Authentication lapse 0 ms.
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:790)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Conexão fechada pela outra ponta
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.read(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:144)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOHeader.readHeaderBuffer(NIOHeader.java:82)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:139)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIOPacket.readFromSocketChannel(NIOPacket.java:101)
    at oracle.net.ns.NIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(NIONSDataChannel.java:80)
    at oracle.net.ano.CryptoNIONSDataChannel.readDataFromSocketChannel(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.prepareForReading(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:98)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineNIO.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineNIO.java:534)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.receive(T4C8TTIdty.java:728)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.doRPC(T4C8TTIdty.java:639)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1544)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:518)
    ... 6 more
```

Pode ser algum problema de infra, mas eu não tenho nenhuma ideia do que possa ser, eu fiz essa classe Main somente para testar, pois esta dando este erro na nossa aplicação real, então queria ter certeza do problema e fiz uma classe básica que só realiza a conexão.

Comment: Pelo erro, o servidor do banco de dados está rejeitando a conexão, pode ser que ele esteja bloqueando o IP do servidor da aplicação?

Comment: é isso que ta difícil de descobrir, pois o controle do banco fica com uma terceirizada aqui, ai estamos tentando contato com eles para eles nos ajudarem